How to get an element with attribute name and again set a new attribute to the same element?
How to get an element with attribute name and again set a new attribute to the same element, suppose I have an <a href="#" myOwnAttributeName="hello"></a>.
Now I know how to select this element using document.querySelectorAll('a[myOwnAttribute="#hello"]') I need to know how will I set an attribute to the selected element. My final  tag should look like <a href="#" myOwnAttributeName="hello" class="class-hello"></a> here I need to add a class name.
Using the setAttribute doesn't work.


document.querySelectorAll('a[myOwnAttribute="#hello"]')
<html>
<a href="#" myOwnAttribute="hello">Click me</a>
</html>




Your snippet isn't showing us how you are using setAttribute so I'm afraid we can't help at the moment. Please include enough code so we can run the snippet and see the problem for ourselves. It's possible you are misinterpreting what querySelectorAll provides.

(only a tip) it's a good practice to use data-my-own-attribute instead of myOwnAttribute

Has this question got anything to do with either jquery or CSS? The snippet as shown so far doesn't include use of either.

remove # when selecting your a tag with a_tag = document.querySelector() Then you can set a_tag.href = 'your href'

@AHaworth have made the changes as required, sorry I am new to this platform

@typed-sigterm done

Using querySelectorAll will create a nodelist so you need to iterate through that nodelist in order to modify the properties of one or all elements. Alternatively if there is a single element that you wish to modify properties/attributes for the querySelector will allow direct access to selected node.
The following snippet shows both approaches - the setting of the new className could more easily be done using node.classList.add("new_class_name") method


document.querySelectorAll('a[ myOwnAttribute="hello" ]').forEach(a=>{
  a.setAttribute('class','class-hello'); //or a.classList.add('class-hello');
});


document.querySelector('a[ myOwnAttribute="goodbye" ]').setAttribute('class','class-goodbye');
.class-hello{
  color:red
}
.class-goodbye{
  color:green
}
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" myOwnAttribute="hello">Click me 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" myOwnAttribute="hello">Click me 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" myOwnAttribute="hello">Click me 3</a></li>
</ul>

<a href="#" myOwnAttribute="goodbye">Or Click me</a>




Please check your original snippet: you don't have a # in value of myOwnAttribute. In your querySelectorAll you have it. Make sure you query against the proper attribute and value.
Please note, if you use querySelectorAll, the return value is a NodeList, so if you wish to use setAttribute, which works on an Element or Node, you have to select one item (in this case [0]) and set the new attribute.
If you have only one matching item, I suggest to use simple querySelector


let tag = document.body.querySelector('a[myOwnAttribute="hello"]');
tags.setAttribute('class', 'class-hello');
<html>

<body>
  <a href="#" myOwnAttribute="hello">Click me</a>
</body>

</html>




there is an attribute dedicated to this and easily accessible via javascript. It's called a data attribute:

data-*
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*
The data-* global attributes form a class of attributes called custom data attributes, that allow proprietary information to be exchanged between the HTML and its DOM representation by scripts.


Using data attributes
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes
HTML is designed with extensibility in mind for data that should be associated with a particular element but need not have any defined meaning. data-* attributes allow us to store extra information on standard, semantic HTML elements without other hacks such as non-standard attributes, or extra properties on DOM.

Possible example from your code. data-attribute can be used as much it is needed and validates.


window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  for (let e of document.querySelectorAll("a[data-my-Attribute]")) {
    let dataStr = e.dataset.myAttribute;
    e.innerText = dataStr;
    e.classList.add('green')
  }
  for (let e of document.querySelectorAll("a[data-other-attr]")) {
    let dataStr = e.dataset.otherattr;
    e.classList.add('red')
  }
});
.green{
  color:green;
  padding:1em;
  display:inline-block;
  border:solid;
}

.red {
color:red;
}

html{
  min-height:100vh;
  place-content:center;
  text-align:center;
}
<a href="#" data-my-Attribute="hello">Click me</a>
<a href="#" data-my-Attribute="the">Click me</a>
<a href="#" data-my-Attribute="world" data-other-attr="make them red" >Click me</a>
<a href ="#" data-another-dataAttribube="another" data-other-attr="make them red">Click Me</a>



for the property classList to add/remove/toggle classNames : see @chrwahl answer's links https://stackoverflow.com/a/79217717/2442099

Use the property classList on the element to add remove class names.
Btw. it is good practice to use the data-* attribute for custom attributes.


// if it is one element:
document.querySelector('a[my-own-attribute="hello"]')
  .classList.add('hello-class');


// if it is multiple elements:
document.querySelectorAll('a[my-own-attribute="hello"]')
  .forEach(elm => elm.classList.add('hello-class'));
.hello-class {
  text-decoration: none;
}
<a href="#" my-own-attribute="hello">Click me</a>
<a href="#" my-own-attribute="hello">Click me</a>



But if is is just for styling the elements using CSS, why not just create a CSS selector for the custom attribute:


a[my-own-attribute="hello"] {
  text-decoration: none;
}
<a href="#" my-own-attribute="hello">Click me</a>
<a href="#" my-own-attribute="hello">Click me</a>



